# Leer números con decimales en consola en Java

Tags: java

Tipo de trabajo: Trabajo individual
Escriba un programa en java que lea un número decimal. Si el número es 0 imprima "cero", si no imprima "positivo" o "negativo". Añada "pequeño" si el valor del número es menor que |1| y "grande" si excede |1000000|
Mi problema es que no me lee decimales y tampoco me deja poner mas `if` o `else` :(

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);  
        
     int numero = sc.nextInt();   
     
     if(numero==0 && numero<1){
         System.out.println("Cero");    
         System.out.println("pequeño");
        } else   
      if(numero>0&& numero<1 )
             System.out.println("Positivo");   
         System.out.println("pequeño");     
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no lee decimales porque estas usando int, que solo lee numeros enteros.. respecto de lo de los if, no se entiende cual es tu problema...

Comment: Que tipo de error te marca para no aceptarte mas `if`?

Answer (score 0):

pues tu problema es en las condiciones, debes repasar los valores logicos de and y or, tambien te sugiero mas orden con tus sentencias poniendoles llaves para no confundirte, el else tiene llaves y en java exise una palabra reservada llamada elif.
dicho esto aqui te dejo el codigo que quieres:

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);

```
 int numero = sc.nextInt();   
 
 if(numero==0){
     System.out.println("Cero");    
    } 
 if(numero==1){  
     System.out.println("pequeño");    
    }
 if(numero<0){
     System.out.println("Negativo");   
    }
 if(numero>0){
     System.out.println("Positivo"); 
    }
 if(numero>1000000){
     System.out.println("grande");
```

}

ese seria el codigo y perdona por tantos if, podrias usar un switch pero nose si ya pasaste esa estructura, espero te sirva

Comment: Java no tiene `elif`...

Comment: @padaleiana tienes razon, era else if ahi